# Uniform continuity of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let *$T:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$* be a linear transformation. Then, is it right to say that $T$ is uniformly continous?

Comment: Yes, since it is Lipschitz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:
$$ T(x+h)-T(x) = T(h) $$
since $T$ is linear. For any $h$, this is bounded by $\lVert T \rVert \lVert h \rVert$, where the second term is just the Euclidean norm of $h$, and the first term is the norm of $T$ defined as $\sup_{\lVert x \rVert =1} \lVert T(x) \rVert$. Hence $T$ is Lipschitz, and so uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thanks Chapper...Can we conclude that a many-one onto linear transformation T is always uniformly continuous?

Comment: This works for *any* linear transformation between complete finite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @Chappers: Finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbf R$  or $\mathbf C$ are always complete.